# Early return from a function in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I am returning items of type SummaryItem from a function

```
 export interface SummaryItem {
        label: string;
        value: string | number | undefined;
    }
```

My goal is to not return an entry when the childcareList is empty. Currently I am returning an entry *"Aktuell Betreuung Kind ":"[]"* and that is not required.

```
function createChildcareItems(key: string): SummaryItem {
     let childcareList = [];
     if (key.includes('current')) {
          childcareList = state['current']['childCare'];
        } else {
          childcareList = state['future']['childCare'];
        }
     if (childcareList.length > 0) {
       for (let i = 0; i < childcareList.length; i++) {
         return {
            label: ChildcareForDTV[key as keyof typeof ChildcareForDTV].concat((i + 1).toString()),
            value: childcareList[i]['days'].toString().concat(' Tage a CHF ').concat((childcareList[i]['rate']).toString()),
            }
          }
        }

     return {
          label: ChildcareForDTV[key as keyof typeof ChildcareForDTV],
          value: '[]',
     }
}
```

ChildcareForDTV ist defined like:

```
export enum ChildcareForDTV {
    current = 'Aktuell Betreuung Kind ',
    future = 'Zukunft Betreuung Kind ',
}
```

Is there a way to somehow early return from a function?

I tried without the final return but that is not possible. I also tried

```
if (childcareList.length == 0) {
      return
}
```

but that generates an error I guess because the interface is expecting a label and a value.

Comment: `key as keyof typeof ChildcareForDTV` <-- This is a bit of a hack. Instead you should constrain the `key` parameter of `function createChildcareItems`, that way you'll get compile-time errors if `key: string` is not a valid `keyof` value.

Comment: Why can't you simply do `return null` from `createChildcareItems`?

Comment: @Dai if I return null I get Type '{ null: any; }' is not assignable to type 'SummaryItem'.

Comment: Change the return-type to `SummaryItem | null`, and update all of `createChildcareItems`'s call-sites to check if it returned `null` and act accordingly.

Comment: *"My goal is to not return an entry when the childcareList is empty."* Then you must specify this in your return type; the way you've declared it, you've said it returns a SummaryItem, but apparently you don't want it to always return one.

Comment: @Dai I tried as you are suggesting but I get an applicaiton general error.

Comment: @scuras "I get an application general error" - eh what?

Comment: @Dai the vue application is giving me an error.

Comment: @Dai thanks for your suggestion to constrain the key parameter of function createChildcareItems. Do you mean  like `function createChildcareItems(key: keyof ChildcareForDTV): SummaryItem `'

Answer (score 0):

To solve the requirement to add as many entries as there are children, I changed the data structure.

```
const rechnerSummary: Summary = {
    title: 'Rechner-summary',
    items: [],
};


function childCareEntries(childCare: ChildCare[], currentOrFuture: string): void {
    for (let i = 0; i < childCare.length; i++) {
        RechnerSummary.items.push(
            {
                label: currentOrFuture == 'current' ? 'Aktuell Betreuung Kind ' + (i + 1) : 'Zukunft Betreuung Kind ' + (i + 1),
                value: childCare[i] ?
                    childCare[i].days.toString() + ' Tage a CHF ' + childCare[i].rate.toString() : '',
            }
        );
    }
}

function addEntry(label: string, value: string): void {
    RechnerSummary.items.push(
        {
            label: label,
            value: value,
        }
    );
}

export function createEntries(state: RechnerState): Summary {

    if (state.current.childCare.length > 0) {
        childCareEntries(state.current.childCare, 'current');
    }

    if (state.future.childCare.length > 0) {
        childCareEntries(state.future.childCare, 'future');
    }
```